# Dropzone JS on submit click upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

that's the code i used to upload my file dropped when i click on the button submit of my form.

My div is droppable, but when i click on the button, nothing append... I don't know if there is a problem with a document ready or somehting..

```
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone(element, {
  url: "/upload.php",                        
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  });

  $('#imgsubbutt').click(function(){           
  myDropzone.processQueue();
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try submit() event for form

```
$('#imgsubbutt').submit(function(){           
 myDropzone.processQueue();
});
```

Comment: It's works, but i discover that's my problem hide an other:

On network, i got a 200 response that's say moove file fail.

Comment: share your code , how you move file.  I have given solution to your titled question. so you should first accept answer !!